# OAuthError: [200] (#200) App cannot edit non-app posts #149

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facepy

I'm trying to make a (hopefully) useful script for public use, which basically sets all the privacy of posts before a certain date (eg, 1 year) to 'only me' automatically.

I'm using the token from graphAPI for permissions.

I'm able to get posts,but when I try to update the privacy setting of the post, i get:

OAuthError: 200 App cannot edit non-app posts

Nearly every permission is enabled in the graphAPI page (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) Is there a way to achieve my objective with this token? or is the only way to create an actual app, request the permission from facebook then do it? =/ That seems overly obstructive for a simple use case..

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Have you managed to do this? I was investigating for the same reason but it seems like is not possible to change privacy settings of old posts.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Facebook art thou a *****